# Javascript Regex Exec not Matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm running the following javascript in a Chrome.  It's yielding a blank string when I'm expecting "123456.78".

```
var amt = "$123,456.78";
digitRegex = /(\d|\.)*/
amtarr = digitRegex.exec(amt);
amtstr = amtarr.join("");
alert(amtstr);
```

Any ideas?

---

**FINAL CODE ENDED UP BEING THIS:**

```
 moneyRegex = /^\$?(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{1,2})?$/
    amt = $("#txtAmt").val();
    amtok = (amt.search(moneyRegex) != -1);
    amtval = 0;
    if (amtok == true) {
         digitRegex = /[\d\.]+/g
         amtarr = digitRegex.exec(amt);
         amtstr = amtarr.join("");
         alert(amtstr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with

```
digitRegex = /(\d|\.)*/g
```

to get all the matches. You could also use:

```
digitRegex = /[\d\.]+/g
```

which should be ok for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @sergio, that did it.  Missing the global flag was the trick.

Answer (score 3):

```
amtstr = amt.replace(/[$,]/g, "");
```

will give you what you want. It removes the commas and the dollar sign from your string, leaving `123456.78`.

Comment: Or, depending on the context, you might consider amt.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '') which will remove all characters which are not digits or '.'

Comment: +1 Thanks @Tim, wish I could check both your answer and sergio.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why `*` doesn't return a result, change it to `+` and it will work.

But there is another bug in your code.

```
digitRegex.exec(amt);
```

returns an array, but it contains only the first match and the position of the next and some other stuff. [See here mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

You have to call `exec` until it returns `null` to get all matches and only the first item in the array contains your match.

```
var amt = "$123,456.78";
digitRegex = /(\d|\.)+/g;
var result = new Array();
while ((amtarr = digitRegex.exec(amt)) != null)
{
result.push(amtarr[0]);
}

amtstr = result.join("");
alert(amtstr);
```